# How to convert map to biglist?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, fastutil

How to convert java.util.Map to fastutil.BigList?

`BigList<Employee> empList= empMap.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see that `BigList` is an interface that extends `java.util.Collection`. You can use `Collectors.toCollection` to collect to this type.

You'll have to choose a specific class that implement the `BigList` interface. For example:

```
BigList<Employee> empList = 
    empMap.values()
          .stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ReferenceBigArrayBigList::new));
```

Of course, if the `BigList` implementation you wish to create has a constructor that accepts a `Collection`, you can simply instantiate it yourself and pass `empMap.values()` to it without using `Stream`s.